# Facebook upgrade to v2.0 before Dec. 25, 2014, is this needed if FB Unity SDK is used?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I saw this message from Facebook:

> *All Facebook-enabled apps will be automaticaly upgraded to API version 2.0 on April 30th, 2015. If you want to get most of the people
>   using your app upgraded to the latest version, you will need apps in
>   app stores before December 25th.*

However, they haven't mentioned any need to upgrade FB Unity SDK. There's no new SDK out for Unity. Does this mean apps that uses FB Unity are not affected by this a-must upgrade? Anyone else using FB Unity SDK?

If I missed anything, please point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just released a beta version with Graph v2.0 support today, I almost missed it because it is below the regular releases!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads

There's lots of information about migration here as well:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/migrate

Comment: I was only looking at the top part of the download page so obviously I missed their latest update. Thanks for pointing it out! :)